# Visual Studio Installer order of component uninstallation

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

Our project has a windows service and UI components. On un-installation the Windows installer tries to kill the processes automatically. I would like installer to kill the UI first and service later so that UI doesn't raise exceptions when service goes out.

How do we change the order which process goes out first in Visual Studio Installer project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change this order because it's generated automatically by Windows Installer.

However, you can try using [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to stop your application processes before [InstallValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) action. This way Windows Installer will no longer try to stop the processes and will simply perform the uninstall.